# Spring Error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

My Main

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hola");
    ApplicationContext context = new   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
    obj.getMessage();
}
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:201)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:9)



Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
          DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:108)
          ... 7 more
```

Comment: Where have you stored Beans.xml ?

Comment: I have src inside Beans-xml and package

Comment: Make sure Beans.xml is in your classpath or give the correct path for Beans.xml.

Comment: yes for sure it is on src

Comment: What do you mean "src"? A suspected reason for your scenario to fail is that the Bean.xml file isn't found by ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(). Please confirm whether or not this is the problem. See the comment by @Pheonix.

Comment: src the source folder. then a have a package inside src and also inside src a have the Beans.xml

Comment: Why the heck is the error in class initializer (`clinit`)? This means that there is something really wrong with your classpath. This has probably nothing to do with the code in the question. What Spring version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The `NullPointerException` error is at almost [impossible location](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.java#L108):

```
static {
    ClassLoader cl = DefaultListableBeanFactory.class.getClassLoader();
    try {
        javaxInjectProviderClass = cl.loadClass("javax.inject.Provider"); /* line 108 */
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // JSR-330 API not available - Provider interface simply not supported then.
    }
}
```

This means that **the class is not able to get its own classloader**. You must have done something really bad to get this error. Check your JRE/JDK, IDE, ...

---

**UPDATE**

[There is no explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29) other than that **you are probably trying to put Spring JARs into JRE's library folder** (`${java.home}/jre/lib`). If that is the case, that is simply wrong. If you really want to include external JARs within JRE, then put them in the official extension directory - `${java.home}/jre/lib/ext`.